# Remove X-Forwarded-For header in Squid 3.0

Tags: proxy, ip, squid, http-headers

Some months ago I was working with Squid 3.0 and managed to get rid of the X-Forwarded-For header completely. Now I am trying to do the same thing but I do not seem to hit the nail.

I have tried `forwarded_for off` but that does not remove the header, it just inserts `unknown` in place of the client IP.

I tried `header_access X-Forwarded-For deny all` but I receive an error about invalid directive. Looking in the function reference it seems that this directive is [deprecated](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/header_access/) in 3.0.

I tried `forwarded_for delete` but this is only [available](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/forwarded_for/) from 3.1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed with:

```
request_header_access X-Forwarded-For deny all
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's the full list you need:-

```
via off
forwarded_for off
follow_x_forwarded_for deny all
request_header_access X-Forwarded-For deny all
header_access X_Forwarded_For deny all
```

Answer (score 1):

For specific domains you can use

```
acl NoXForwardedFor dst "/usr/pbi/squid-amd64/etc/squid/NoXForwardedFor.txt"

request_header_access X-Forwarded-For deny NoXForwardedFor
```

where `NoXForwarded.txt` contains domain names.

Answer (score 1):

you can set forwarded_for directive to truncate

> forwarded_for truncate

this will remove all existing X-Forwarded-For entries, and place the client IP as the sole entry

For more about this directive visit [squid : forwarded_for configuration directive](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/forwarded_for/)