# Hide squid in the header

Tags: squid

I have a squid server installed, and I'd like it to be hidden when looking into the headers.

First of all, I was getting both squid and the version on the headers:

```
curl -i ip_address

HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Server: squid/3.1.10
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 04 Feb 2015 18:58:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 3157
X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_URL 0
Vary: Accept-Language
Content-Language: en
X-Cache: MISS from host.example.com
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from host.example.com:80
Via: 1.0 host.example.com (squid/3.1.10)
Connection: close
```

I then set the following directive in /etc/squid/squid.conf:

```
httpd_suppress_version_string on
```

And now I'm not getting the squid version:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Server: squid
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 04 Feb 2015 19:11:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 13
X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_URL 0
Vary: Accept-Language
Content-Language: en
X-Cache: MISS from host.example.com
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from host.example.com:80
Via: 1.0 host.example.com (squid)
Connection: close
```

But I'd like to hide squid from the headers.

I get the same results when I try to use the machine as a proxy, f.i. by using:

```
curl -i -x http://user:password@ip_address:80 http://iplocation.net
```

I've tried the solutions form this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/102668/remove-x-forwarded-for-header-in-squid-3-0), but it's not working.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If squid has trouble retrieving a given URL it returns it's own error page.

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/241918/how-can-i-prevent-squid-from-being-detected .

Comment: It's not working for me. squid -v shows that it's been compiled with --enable-follow-x-forwarded-for.

Answer (score 4):

```
reply_header_access X-Squid-Error deny all
```

More info at [Squid docs](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/reply_header_access/)

Comment: Code is good, but some reasons for it and a link to docs would make it worth voting for.

Comment: @chicks It does not allow to use corresponding header in response. Nice solution Omid!

Answer (score 3):

If you have your squid configured with "--enable-http-violations", 
check [reply-header-replace](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/reply_header_replace/)
option.
Example:

> reply_header_replace Server Foo/1.0